# Apply Column Filtering in Gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is populated at runtime with a table with unknow number of columns which are not known before hand.

I want to apply column filtering on all columns with Drop Down List.

How can I achieve it. Using Jquery, Linq or simple C sharp Coding.

```
public partial class DetailView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static int y = 0;

    public static String colName = "";
    public static Boolean flag = false;
    static String folder = "";
    static public MySqlConnection conn = null;
    static public DropDownList dp = null;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

            base.OnInit(e);
            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new MySqlConnection(strcon);
            conn.Open();
            Response.Write(Session["cols"].ToString());
            Response.Write(Session["id"].ToString());
            //  Response.Write("qw");
            folder = Session["folderName"].ToString();
            colName = Session["cols"].ToString();


            GridBind(folder, colName, flag);

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }

    public void GridBind(String folder, String colName, Boolean val)
    {   
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Columns.Clear();
        y = 0;


        MySqlDataAdapter da;
        if (val == false)
        {

            da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from " + folder + "", conn);
        }
        else
        {
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from " + folder + " where abc= '" + colName + "'", conn);
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        da.Fill(dt);



        foreach (DataColumn coloumn in dt.Columns)
        {

            if (!coloumn.ColumnName.Equals("emp"))
            {


                var linkF = new TemplateField();
                linkF.HeaderText = coloumn.ColumnName;
                linkF.HeaderTemplate = new LinkColumn(ListItemType.Header, coloumn.ColumnName,folder);
                linkF.ItemTemplate = new LinkColumn(ListItemType.Item, coloumn.ColumnName,folder);


                GridView1.Columns.Add(linkF);

            }
            else if (coloumn.ColumnName.Equals("emp"))
            {
                //Response.Write("Came");
                BoundField bfield = new BoundField();

                ////Initalize the DataField value.
                bfield.DataField = coloumn.ColumnName;

                ////Initialize the HeaderText field value.
                bfield.HeaderText = coloumn.ColumnName;
                GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield);




            }

        }

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;


            GridView1.DataBind();

    }


    class LinkColumn : DetailView, ITemplate
    {
        int id;
        ListItemType _item;
        String colN = null;
        String fold;
        public LinkColumn(ListItemType item, String colNa, String f)
        {
            _item = item;
            colN = colNa;
            fold = f;
        }
        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {

            switch (_item)
            {
                case ListItemType.Header:
                    DetailView.dp = new DropDownList();
                    Label lb = new Label();
                    MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("select distinct " + colN + " from " + fold + "", conn);

                    MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable d = new DataTable();
                    ad.SelectCommand = cm;
                    ad.Fill(d);
                    DetailView.dp.DataTextField = colN;
                    DetailView.dp.DataValueField = colN;
                    DetailView.dp.DataSource = d;
                    DetailView.dp.DataBind();
                    lb.Text = colN.ToUpperInvariant();
                    dp.AutoPostBack = true;
                    dp.EnableViewState = true;
                    //    DetailView.dp.ID = y.ToString();
                    y++;
                    container.Controls.Add(lb);

                    container.Controls.Add(DetailView.dp);
                    //   DetailView.dp.ID = DetailView.y.ToString();
                    //    Response.Write(_Default.dp.ID);
                    DetailView.dp.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dp_Selected);


                    break;
                case ListItemType.Item:
                    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
                    tb1.Enabled = false;
                    tb1.DataBinding += new EventHandler(tb1_Data);
                    tb1.Columns = 30;
                    container.Controls.Add(tb1);
                    break;
            }

        }

        void tb1_Data(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
            GridViewRow cont = (GridViewRow)txt.NamingContainer;
            object dataV = DataBinder.Eval(cont.DataItem, colN);
            if (dataV != DBNull.Value)
            {
                txt.Text = dataV.ToString();
            }
        }

        void dp_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable a = new DataTable();
            DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;
            String name = list.SelectedValue;
            // String ID = list.ID.ToString();
            // Session["id"] = ID;
            Session["cols"] = name;
            DetailView.colName = Session["cols"].ToString();
            DetailView.flag = true;
            //   Response.Write(DetailView.colName);


            GridBind(fold, DetailView.colName, true);

        }
    }
}

When i am calling GridBind function from event handler it is giving Null pointer Excpetion at GridView1.DataSource = null;
```

My GridView1 is present in DetailView.aspx
}

Any help be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried? show us your code.

Comment: place the gridview in update panel and update on dropdown change event. But I think its better to draw the grid dynamically and use ajax + jquery to acheive the functionality (less load and no postpack)

Comment: Try using open source Dynamic.cs that will help you if the number of columns are unknown. It is under name space System.Linq.Dynamic. Whole code is available on internet. its an open source. If any queries ask I have worked on this.